# Exposed date filter "date selection form element" and "granularity" settings are missing

Tags: views

I would like to create a block view from a content type which has an exposed date field. This has to be a dropdown field where only the years are listed.
There is no setting possibility of the exposed date field where I could define these properties that are available in Drupal 7:

- Date selection form element
- Filter granularity
- Starting year
- Ending year

[image: exposed date field settings in D7]

I installed these modules, but none of them fixed the problem:

- views_block_filter_block
- better_exposed_filters

Any idea or hint?

Comment: it looks like a missing function: [PP-1 Views Date Filter Datetime Granularity Option](https://www.drupal.org/node/2868014)