# Unable to load class \Drush\VersionControl\Backup

Tags: drush

I keep getting this error :
*Unable to load class \Drush\VersionControl\Backup*
 every time i attempt to update my Drupal install from **8.4.0 to 8.4.2**.

I am running  the composer provided drush **Drush Version   :  8.1.15**

Now here is what i have tried:

- **drush up drupal --debug**
  Unable to load class \Drush\VersionControl\Backup
- **drush up drupal --debug  --version-control=svn**
  No valid version control or backup engine found
- **drush up drupal --debug  --version-control=git**
  No valid version control or backup engine found
- **drush up drupal --debug  --no-backup**
  No valid version control or backup engine found

if anyone could answer any of these question for me, i would really appreciate it:
How do i turn off version control? 
How do i set the valid version control that this thing is complaining about?
How do i set the backup engine?

Note: some solutions out there mentioned that we have to remove the composer provided version and install drush to a different location. To be honest I do not want to use that solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use Composer to update Drupal?

Comment: Be prepared to have this sort of problems when you don't [use composer to build your D8.4+ sites](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2017-03-24/how-do-i-migrate-existing-d8-site-into-a-composer-managed#comment-12328945). Also take a look at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/242260/how-do-i-update-core-to-8-4 on how to solve your problem in an alternative way.

Answer (score 4):

> I am running the composer provided drush **Drush Version : 8.1.15**

Drupal 8.4 requires Drush 9, so upgrade your Drush for starters.

```
composer global require drush/drush:master
```

> [image]
>   http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/

Comment: AFAIK that's not true anymore, the 8.4 incompatibility has been fixed with Drush 8.1.15

Comment: @Hudri one would think that in that case the info shown in the above screenprint would have been updated also, no?

Comment: @Perrie.Vriens I've multiple sites running with Drupal 8.4.x and Drush 8.1.15, and so far I've not found any issues. I know the description hasn't been updated, but it just works for me. Also so https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/3023

Comment: @Hudri Imagine an airplane with automatic pilot software based on Drupal 8.4, using Drush 8.x. How would you feel flying at 30,000 feet knowing the instructions of the manufacturer of the airplane state it has to be Drush 9? E.g. because nobody ever tested it enough with Drush 8.x? PS to OPer: congratulations with the bounty !

Answer (score 0):

## Install drush globally.

```
composer global require drush/drush:8.x
```

Works on Drupal 7 and 8.

You might have trouble locating the drush file to run as it will be at another location now. You can try to find it by running `composer global show drush/drush`  Ideally change your PATH: settings to this.

Answer (score -1):

### Remove Drush from the project composer and use globally installed Drush.

While working on a Drupal 7 install, with Drush 8 and using Drush launcher.